# Get random range google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have managed with VBA and Excel to achieve my purposes, but I'd like to move to google spreadsheet for particular reasons.

I'm trying to replicate a code that works just fine in VBA.

It's simple, I have a sheet with a bank of questions in column A, and I'd like a macro that can select 1 random question and copy it to a second sheet.

I'm having trouble understanding how I can access a random cell, copy it and paste it to the second sheet. Some plain explanation would be appreciated since I have very little or non-existent knowledge of programming or javascript.

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetID");

  //Say I have 10 questions in the BANKSHEET, for instance
  var rQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1); 

  //What goes in A1? So that I can access the range randomly according to rQuestion value.
  var inputRange =  ss.getSheetByName("BANKSHEET").getRange("A1");
  var inputValues = inputRange.getValues();
  var outputRange = ss.getSheetByName("QUIZZ").getRange("A1").setValues(inputValues);
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification? I think that there are several solutions for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points :

- Retrieve the number of cells at "A1:A" from sheet of "BANKSHEET".
- Retrieve randomly one of the number.
- Copy the cell value of the retrieved number to "A1" of "QUIZZ".

#### Modified script :

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetID");

  // Retrieve randomly a value from sheet of BANKSHEET
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("BANKSHEET");
  var src = sheet.getRange("A" + (1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * sheet.getLastRow())));

  // Put the value to "A1" at sheet of QUIZZ
  var dst = ss.getSheetByName("QUIZZ").getRange("A1");
  src.copyTo(dst);
}
```

#### Note :

- It supposes that there are values in only column A of "BANKSHEET".
- This modified script randomly retrieves one value from column A of "BANKSHEET" every time.

  - If you don't want to use the value which has already been used, please modify the script for your situation.

#### Reference :

- [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.